# why the GridView RowDeleted event is not working with objectdatasource control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I added the rowDeleted Event to my code in order to recive a message if the row is Deleted by using the AffectedRows Proparty but the event is not fireup

1-Here is the the code that is used :

```
       ( protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            if(e.AffectedRows > 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "the Row Deleted";
            }
        }
```

2- this is the GrideView That I Used:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>   
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Education" HeaderText="Education" SortExpression="Education" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetEmployees" TypeName="Employee_Mangment.Data.EmployeeDataAccess" UpdateMethod="UpdateEmployee" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="Original_{0}" DeleteMethod="DeleteEmployee">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Education" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Education" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Education" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>

        </div> 
    </form>
```

3-this is my Model:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Education { get; set; }
    }
```

4-this is my dataaccessLayer :

```
    public class EmployeeDataAccess
    {
        public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
                {
                    CommandText = "select ID,Name,EducationType from Employee join Education on EduID = EducationID",
                    Connection = con
                };

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Employee employee = new Employee()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]),
                            Name = rdr["Name"].ToString(),
                            Education = rdr["EducationType"].ToString(),
                        };

                        employees.Add(employee);
                    }
                }

                return employees;

            }
        }

        public static void UpdateEmployee( int Original_ID, string Original_Name ,string Original_Education , string Name , string Education)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) 
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
                {
                    CommandText = "_try",
                    Connection = con
                };

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameterOginalID = new SqlParameter("@Original_ID", Original_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterOginalID);

                SqlParameter parameterOginalName = new SqlParameter("@Original_Name", Original_Name);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterOginalName);

                SqlParameter parameterOginalEducation = new SqlParameter("@Original_Education", Original_Education);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterOginalEducation);

                SqlParameter ParameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", Name);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParameterName);

                SqlParameter parameterEducation = new SqlParameter("@Education", Education);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEducation);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        public static void DeleteEmployee(int Original_ID, string Original_Name ,string Original_Education)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
                {
                    CommandText = "delete from Employee where ID = @Original_ID  and Name = @Original_Name and EducationID = (select EduID from Education where EducationType = @Original_Education)",
                    Connection = con
                };


                SqlParameter OginalID = new SqlParameter("@Original_ID", Original_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(OginalID);

                SqlParameter OginalName = new SqlParameter("@Original_Name", Original_Name);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(OginalName);

                SqlParameter OginalEducation = new SqlParameter("@Original_Education", Original_Education);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(OginalEducation);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
    }
```

5-Here is the _try Stored Prosedure :

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[_try] (@Original_ID int, @Name varchar(100),@Education varchar(100),@Original_Name varchar(100),@Original_Education varchar(100))
as
begin
    update Employee set Name = @Name ,EducationID = (select EduID from Education where EducationType = @Education) where ID = @Original_ID and Name = @Original_Name and EducationID = (select EduID from Education where EducationType = @Original_Education)
End
```

i need to know what is the problem that makes the RowDeleted does not fire

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the deleting event at GridView Tag:

```
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
```

So your GridView code should look something like this:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Education" HeaderText="Education" SortExpression="Education" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

At the code behind, there should have an event handler created for this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to hook-up the event handler with the event in the `<asp:GridView>` tag in the .aspx file.
It should be like this `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" **OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted**>`